# Javascript popup don't get value from php parent page

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm doing wrong?

This is the JavaScript code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function popupIp(url) 
    {
    window.open(url,'popupWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,
menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,width=350,height=320,screenX=150,
screenY=150,top=50,left=50')
    }
    </script>
    </head>
```

And here I call the popup:

```
    <a href="#" <?='onclick="popupIp(\''.tep_href_link('ip-address-popup.php',  'ut='
 . $visit['bp_ip']), '&submit=Process' .'\'); return false;"';?>>
    <?php echo $visit["bp_ip"] . '</a>
```

I echo 
 `$visit["bp_ip"] and $ut`
on popup but there are no values.

Comment: Your `<a>` is ill formed and honestly I can't tell what you are trying to pass it with your javaScript function in it.

Comment: I know it is ill formed. That is why I come here. I'm trying to pass the value $visit["bp_ip"] which is the ip address of a visitor giving a new name as a variable $ut.

Comment: And that value is a url?

Comment: Part of it. When the popup open, the url is for example, this: http://www.domainname.com/ip-address-popup.php?ut=98.24.41.20&submit=Process. When I echo $ut on the popup, nothing is shown. Just as a clarification, before upgrading the website to php 5.4 it worked.

Comment: Your code is almost impossible to read, if you resist the urge to try to cram everything into one line you will see the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$popup = '<a href="#" onclick="popupIp(\'';
$popup .= tep_href_link('ip-address-popup.php', 'ut=' . $visit['bp_ip']);
$popup .= '&submit=Process\'); return false;">';
$popup .= $visit["bp_ip"];
$popup .= '</a>';
echo $popup;
?>
```

Your example had so many errors in it, hidden by putting it all into one unreadable line, that it took a while to unravel it. One liners ALWAYS hide bugs and make code hard to read, it's a habit well worth breaking if you plan on doing more programming, particularly on a professional level. Clean, debuggable, easy to read, code, that's the key.

I'm not 100% sure this is what you intended, but it's at least readable and debuggable so you can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Sorry about the one line. I'm still trying to make a line-break here but I will keep this in mind. I'm still unable to get the ip value in the popup. Thank you.

Comment: With the above code block I gave, which is I believe correct, show now the full html output in your page code, the rendered php that is. ie, from <a.. to </a>. Your version had bugs in it which probably broke the expected url you have in there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by trying to make a linebreak, or where you want it. For example, if you want it to break after </a> then just do: $popup .= "</a>\n";

Comment: This is the html output: <td class="VisitorTableContent">
<a href="#" onclick="popupIp('http://www.domainname.com/ip-address-popup.php?ut=166.184.152.3&submit=Process'); return false;">166.184.152.3</a></td>

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Unless you have register_globals set to on, $ut will not be set, that's: $_GET['ut'] not $ut. So $ut showing nothing is correct and expected behavior. I'd missed that in your initial post. I don't know where $visit["bp_ip"] comes from so I can't say anything about that. If all you want to do is show their ip address, then just use: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] which is the ip address.

Comment: This is all I needed: $ut = $_GET['ut']; - BTW, $visit["bp_ip"] comes from a table and yes, this is oscommerce. Thank you